# Mathematical notation for formulas involving trees

Tags: graph-theory, notation, trees

I am working on document that requires me to write such things as "$T_1$ is a descendant of $T_0$", or "$N_1$ is an parent of $N_2$".  For now, I've been highjacking set notation for use in formulas, like

$$
f(A) = \sum_{B\subset A}g(B)
$$

where $B$ are descendants of $A$, but as I run into more relationships (e.g. parent vs ancestor) I find myself having to invent some notation.

Is there an existing (and hopefully well-established) notation associated with tree relationships which I can use in formulas instead of having to invent my own?

Comment: What kinds of things are you trying to do with these trees?

Comment: @ikh can you please share the notation that you invented? I really want to use it

Comment: @raindrop As far as I recall, the project wrapped up and I didn't have to solve that problem. But I was experimenting with various variants of the set notation

Comment: @raindrop See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define a [binary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) $\mathbin{R}$ that denotes “is a parent of”. Then:

- $\mathbin{R} \circ \mathbin{R}$ is the
  [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Operations_on_binary_relations)
  of $R$ with itself. It denotes “is a grandparent of”.
- $\mathbin{R} \circ \mathbin{R} \circ \mathbin{R} = \mathbin{R}^{\circ 3}$ denotes “is a great-grandparent of”.
- $\mathbin{R}^+$ is the [transitive
  closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of $R$. It
  denotes “is an ancestor of”.
- $\mathbin{R}^\mathsf{T}$ is the
  [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation) of $R$.
  It denotes “is a child of”.
- $(\mathbin{R}^\mathsf{T})^+$ denotes “is a descendant of”.